# Rails Nested Attributes and Custom Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, nested-forms

I'm fairly new to both Ruby and Rails (using 2.3.8), so forgive me if I'm missing something really obvious here but I've been struggling with this for a while and my searches have been fruitless.

In my code I have Plans, and a Plan has many Plan_Steps. Each Plan_Step has a number (to indicate '1st', '2nd', etc). I have a form to update a Plan, and I need to validate that each Plan_Step has a unique number. The code below might give a better explanation of the design:

models/plan.rb:

```
Class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plan_steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :plan_steps, :allow_destroy => true

  validate :validate_unique_step_numbers

  # Require all steps to be a unique number
  def validate_unique_step_numbers
    step_numbers = []
    plan_steps.each do |step|
      #puts step.description
      if !step.marked_for_destruction? && step_numbers.include?(step.number) 
        errors.add("Error Here")
      elsif !step.marked_for_destruction?
        step_numbers << step.number
      end
  end      
end
```

controllers/plans_controller.rb:

```
...
def update
  @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  if @plan.update_attributes(params[:plan])
    #Success
  else
    #Fail
  end
end
```

Now when my form submits an update, the params hash looks like this:

```
  {"commit"=>"Submit", 
   "action"=>"update", 
   "_method"=>"put",
   "authenticity_token"=>"NHUfDqRDFSFSFSFspaCuvi/WAAOFpg5AAANMre4x/uu8=", 
   "id"=>"1", 
   "plan"=>{
     "name"=>"Plan Name", 
     "plan_steps_attributes"=>{
       "0"=>{"number"=>"1", "id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"0", "description"=>"one"}, 
       "1"=>{"number"=>"2", "id"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"0", "description"=>"three"}, 
       "2"=>{"id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"1"}},            
   "controller"=>"plans"}
```

The database contains entries for Plan_Steps with the following:

```
ID=1, Number=1, Description='one'
ID=2, Number=2, Description='two'
```

Notice that ID=2 exists with Number=2, and what I'm trying to do is delete ID=2 and create a new entry (ID=3) with Number=2.

OK, so with that set up, here is my problem:

When I call plan_steps in the validation, it appears to be pulling the values from the database instead of from the params[] array passed to update_attributes.

For example, if I uncomment the 'puts' line in the validation, I see the descriptions of the Plan_Steps as they exist in the database, not as they exist from the passed-in parameters. This means I can't validate the incoming Plan_Steps.

I can't do validation in the Plan_Steps model, either, since unless I'm mistaken the validation will occur against the database (and not the parameters passed in).

I apologize if this is a poorly worded question, but it's fairly specific. If you need any clarification, please ask.

And remember, I'm a noob, so I could easily be making some really stupid mistake.

Comment: Reflecting on this a bit, my question could really be boiled down to:

When updating a model with nested attributes, is there any way to access the values of the associated/nested models as they were passed in (through the params[] hash)?

In my example, when I try to access "plan_steps" I'd like to get the values passed to "update_attributes" instead of the values from the DB. Any way to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Any validation you perform in the model is going to look at the database, as far as I know.  If you want to compare the values in the params, you'll need to do so before you reach the db validations (not recommended at all).  Also, just for future reference, your validation can be achieved using the built in validates_uniqueness_of like this:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :number, :scope => :plan_id
```

As for what you're trying to get accomplished in the end (and keep in mind I don't know much about your project, so take this with a grain of salt), I'd recommend calculating the step position on the back-end instead of relying on user input.  I'd make specific suggestions, but it's tough to say without knowing how your collecting your "number" value (drag/drop, manual entry, list location, etc...).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I BELIEVE I've tried the validates_uniqueness_of already, and the problem was that at the time of validation, the conflicting step that is marked for deletion was not yet deleted, so a conflict existed. Regardless, I will try this a little later.

As for collecting the number, it is managed by a bit of Javascript in hidden values. Users shouldn't be able to mess up the numbers unless they tamper with the inputs. Still, I don't think how I collect the data from the form will solve the problem I'm having here.

Comment: Well, because the position is always stored in a hidden value, and not liable to user error, then I would just give them all sequential values in the form and handle it on the backside.  In your example, the "number" would be 1,2,3 with 2 scheduled to be deleted.  Then you could call a PlanStep.reorder function that goes through and orders them now that the 2 is gone.  Another option would just be to create new steps with the last number (Plan.plan_steps.size + 1) and let them use drag/drop to reorder.  Again, I'm not looking at your project, this is just how I handle it in these cases.

Comment: Now, assuming I do go the reordering route, my question is at what point do I do this reordering? Right now in my mind it looks like this:
    User input comes in ->
    Call "@plan.update_attributes(params[:plan])" -> 
    Save/Delete steps -> 
    Call reorder function, making another DB call to update the step numbers.
  
I'm trying to avoid that second DB call because I have all the info and it should be possible at save time for the plan model, rather than afterwards. If I must do it afterwards, then I suppose I shall. Something feels wrong. Maybe I'm expecting too much from Rails.

Comment: There could be a better way, I don't really know.  The way I typically handle this is to assign the location as the next in the list and let them reorder via drag/drop as needed (because that's what's worked best given the scenarios I've encountered).  My suggestion at this point would be to make it work, mark it with a TODO note to look at later, and move on with your project.  Better to make some progress and come back later after you've learned more. I'm always amazed at how much I learn over the course of every project.

Comment: Agreed, and thanks for the help. I took the "move along" approach and I'll come back to it when the time is right. I will leave this question open and I'll answer it if I ever figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

433887,

I wrote some tests for your question, as I was unsure myself of how accepts_nested_attributes was working internally. There was a gotcha where records that did not exist would be silently ignored if they contained an 'id' attribute in the params that were passed in. See below.

```
#test/fixtures/plans.yml
only_plan:
   id: 1

#test/fixtures/plan_steps.yml
one:
  plan_id: 1
  number: 1
  description: one

two:
  plan_id: 1
  number: 2
  description: two

#test/unit/plan_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class PlanTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  # These are just helpers I like to use so that Test::Unit gives good 
  # feedback as to which call you're testing.
  def assert_to(assump, inst_sub, meth, *args )
    assert_equal assump, instance_variable_get(inst_sub).send(meth, *args), 
    "#{inst_sub}.#{meth}(#{args.inspect}) should have been #{assump.inspect}"
  end

  def assert_chain(assump, inst_sub, *meths)
    assert_equal( assump, meths.inject(instance_variable_get(inst_sub)) do |s,i|
      s.send(*i)
    end, 
    "#{inst_sub}.#{meths.join('.')} should have been #{assump.inspect}")
  end


  test "example given" do
    assert_chain 2, :@only_plan, :plan_steps, :size

    # attributes=, and then save() is 
    # an equivalent operation to update_attributes().
    # I only split them here to show the marked_for_destruction? portion.
    @only_plan.attributes= {
      :plan_steps_attributes =>
      {
        "0"=>{"number"=>"1", "id"=>@one.id.to_s, 
          "_destroy"=>"0", "description"=>"one"}, 
        "1"=>{"number"=>"2", "id"=>(@two.id + 1).to_s, 
          "_destroy"=>"0", "description"=>"three"}, 
        "2"=>{"id"=>@two.id.to_s, 
          "_destroy"=>"1"},
      }
    }

    #The validations of the _resulting_ affected records pass
    assert_chain true, :@only_plan, :errors, :empty? 
    @two_in_plan_steps = @only_plan.plan_steps.detect{|x| x.id == @two.id}
    assert_chain true, :@two_in_plan_steps, :marked_for_destruction?
    #Three was ignored because of the id

    assert_chain true, :@only_plan, :save 

    #The relevant records have been created and destroyed
    @plan_step_set = @only_plan.reload.plan_steps.reload.map{|i| 
      [i.description, i.number]}

    assert_chain true, :@two_in_plan_steps, :destroyed?

    assert_to [['one', 1]], :@plan_step_set, :sort 

    #removing the id makes it appear correctly
    assert_to( true, :@only_plan, :update_attributes, {
      :plan_steps_attributes =>
      {
        "1"=>{"number"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"0", "description"=>"three"}, 
      }
    }
    )

    @plan_step_set = @only_plan.reload.plan_steps.reload.map{|i| 
      [i.description, i.number]}

    assert_to [['one', 1], ['three', 2]], :@plan_step_set, :sort

  end
end
```

Of course, the given test data doesn't actually use your validation at all as written.

It's hard to tell exactly what you would want the validation to do. "Each PlanStep has a number (to indicate '1st', '2nd', etc)" would seem to indicate that maybe you're trying to store ordinals for the plan_steps in the db ('1st', '2nd', etc rather than '1st', '3rd', some other unique number.) Ordinals are hard to work with, and conveniently, easy to generate. As long as the 'number's you're putting into the database will put the rows in the correct order, you can assign them ordinals by walking through the set of plan_steps in an after_initialize callback, or though adding [mysql hacks](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) to the association.

But your example data and code seems to indicate otherwise, so there's not really any solid advice we can give you.

Are you trying to let the user reorder some elements, in which case you probably want the ordinal solution above without any validation on the position (just good defaults so that new PlanSteps place themselves at the end of the list,) or are the 'number's significant and importantly sparse?

Under what, if any, conditions should your customers see errors when they're making and using these PlanSteps?

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. Since I originally asked this question I've become a proud papa, so it had slipped my mind until now. 

Each plan has ordered steps. Lets say a user put two steps in the wrong order, and wanted to reorder them? Or, perhaps, they wanted to add an additional step between the two? The problem is I didn't want duplicate step numbers. An error should occur if two steps have the same number (aka the 'ordinal').

I don't have my code in front of me at the moment, but I believe I solved this using :before_validation and simply setting the numbers if incorrect